# navigation bar color on IOS 7

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7

When I tried to run my app developed using xcode 4.6 on IOS 7, the navigation bar colors looked different, they appear on the default blue color while the back button is showing the same color as you assigned to, Is there any way to fix that? to change the navigation bar color?

Thank you

Comment: Code? Screenshot? Something? It's hard to tell what you think is wrong , what you expect, and what you've tried to do from your question.

Comment: @Benoit here is a screenshot !http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/1676/bc7n.png it is suppose to be all brown as in ios 6

Comment: Some code sample on how you set UINavigationBar color might help